# Bold Text in Email Template based on IF condition in Salesforce

Tags: html, salesforce, apex, visualforce, email-templates

I need to bold a Text based on an IF statement in Salesforce Visualforce Email Template. Could someone please help me. In below apex html tags I need to bold **Required** Text when If Condition gets True.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(relatedTo.Quote__r.Margin__c)),NOT(ISBLANK(relatedTo.Quote__r.Threshold__c)),relatedTo.Quote__r.Margin__c<relatedTo.Quote__r.Threshold__c), 
                            "Required", "Not Required" )}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks bit nasty (duplicated tags) but should be pretty reliable. You could put the condition straight in `rendered` attributes but if you ever need to change it you could forget and do it in just 1 place, that'd be "fun" bug.

```
<apex:variable var="condition" value="{!AND(NOT(ISBLANK(relatedTo.Quote__r.Margin__c)),NOT(ISBLANK(relatedTo.Quote__r.Threshold__c)),relatedTo.Quote__r.Margin__c<relatedTo.Quote__r.Threshold__c)}" />

<apex:outputPanel layout="inline" rendered="{!condition}">
    <b>Required</b>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel layout="inline" rendered="{!!condition}">
    Not Required<!-- you could also put it in `value`-->
</apex:outputPanel>
```

If you don't want repeated code you could try something like

```
<apex:variable var="condition" value="{!AND(NOT(ISBLANK(relatedTo.Quote__r.Margin__c)),NOT(ISBLANK(relatedTo.Quote__r.Threshold__c)),relatedTo.Quote__r.Margin__c<relatedTo.Quote__r.Threshold__c)}" />

<apex:outputText value="{!IF(condition, 'Required', 'Not Required')}" style="{!IF(condition, 'font-weight:bold, '')}" />
```

You should test the 2nd versions, what if email client decides to ignore styles. Although inline styles like that should be fine, "just" CSS in `<style>` tag tends to be unreliable...